# UPDATE one table upon INSERT INTO another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with two tables:

- devices
- temperature

The schema follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS devices(
  device_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  device_name varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  last_record_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT '1995-10-30 10:30:00'
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temperature(
  device_id integer NOT NULL,
  temperature decimal NOT NULL,
  record_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT temperature_device_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (device_id)
    REFERENCES devices (device_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

The devices table keeps a list of all the devices. So there is a unique id for each device. The temperature table aggregates data from all of the devices. You can select by device_id to see all the entries that pertain to a specific device.

I have the constraint that I cannot delete from the devices table because the temperature table depends on it. I would also like the devices table to be updated when a new record is inserted into the temperature table.

That is, the record_time from a new record in the temperature should become the last_record_time for that device's entry in the devices table. That way I always know when was the last time a device inserted data.

I am currently doing this programmatically. I insert records, and immediate select them right back out and write into the other table. This is introducing some bugs. So, I would prefer to automate this at the database level. How can I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use trigger to do this implicitly.

create trigger on temperature table for events such as insert/delete/update and update temparature table inside that trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_last_record_time()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE devices
    SET last_record_time = NEW.record_time
    WHERE device_id = NEW.device_id;

    RETURN NEW;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON temperature
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_last_record_time();
```

Comment: Nope, read question carefully: That is, the record_time from a new record in the temperature should become the last_record_time for that device's entry in the devices table.... User wants to update the device table.... Trigger needs to be created in temparature table

Comment: For the temperature table, how would that be written? a trigger.

Comment: @mittal , trigger should be written on temperature table for insert action and it should update devie table record_time

Comment: @Nishad, yeah I am telling the same. See my last statement "Trigger needs to be created in temparature table"

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to using trigger would be CTE:

```
WITH ins AS (
  INSERT INTO temperature (device_id, temperature, record_time)
  VALUES (1, 35.21, '2018-01-30 09:55:23')
  RETURNING device_id, record_time
)
UPDATE devices AS d SET last_record_time = ins.record_time
FROM ins
WHERE d.device_id = ins.device_id;
```

Comment: So that statement would replace my traditional insert into temperature table?

Comment: Yes. This is one query.

Answer (score 0):

For Deleting row from child table Use Cascaded delete when creating foreign key it will automatically delete records from the child table when Parent table record will be deleted

Comment: I am not trying to delete. I am trying to update one table when new data is inserted into temperature